# Java String.replaceAll doesn't replace a quote with escaped quote

Tags: java

Having a hard time replacing a quote with an escaped quote. I have a string that has the value of 'Foo "bar" foobar', and I am trying to replace the quotes around bar with escaped quotes, and it isn't working. I am going crazy.

```
s=s.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");
```

I would expect s to have the value of 'foo \"bar\" foobar', but it doesn't. Any help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) uses regular expressions - in which the backslash just escapes the next character, even in the replacement.

Use [`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead and it's fine... or you can double the backslash in the second argument if you want to use the regular expression form:

```
String after = before.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

This could be useful if you need to match the input using regular expressions, but I'd strongly recommend using the non-regex form unless you actually *need* regex behaviour.

Personally I think it was a mistake for methods in `String` to use regular expressions to start with - things like `foo.split(".")` which will split on *every character* rather than on periods, completely unexpectedly to the unwary developer.

Answer (score 12):

Use `s = s.replace("\"", "\\\"");`, which is the non-regex version.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape both replace all arguments because they are regex!

```
@Test
public void testReplace() {
    assertEquals("foo\\\"bar\\\"",
                 "foo\"bar\"".replaceAll("\\\"", "\\\\\\\""));
}
```

So if you want to write `"` you need to escape the regex -> `\"` but because you are in java you need to escape the `\` and `"` for java to, so you get `\\\\"`. (that is the search parameter).

For the replace parameter you want to have `\"` -> in regex: `\\\"` -> in Java `\\\\\\\"`

Comment: exactly the explanation I thought was missing above! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
s=s.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");
```

But you should really go with `replace(...)` as the others here advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use;

```
s=s.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "'Foo \"Bar\" Bar'";
System.out.println(str);        
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\""));
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow below program and use > s.replace("/"."//");

```
public class stringbackslash {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s="\";
        s=s.replace("\", "\\");
        System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```